# Adding row to QTableView slows the app down after a lot of inserts

Tags: c++, qt4, qtableview

I have a QTableView thats using a model i made which extends the QAbstractTableModel.  The model uses a

```
QList< QVector<QString> * >
```

as the collection.  The table view is used to display logging messages from the application so the collection will eventually get extremely large... After it inserts  a few thousand rows i notice the table view starts to slow down a lot and eventually the view freezes for a few seconds before refreshing.. Is it the type of collection im using thats making it slow down soo much?  Is there a better way to store the data thats being inserted?  Does the QTableView support a large amount of data?

**Edit**

Posted code on Qt forumn:
http://www.qtforum.org/article/37326/qttableview-slows-down-when-a-lot-of-data-is-inserted.html

Comment: How does your data method looks like? Also how do you insert data into model?

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used `QTableView` displaying ~10000 rows so `QTableView` is capable of supporting it but your collection leaves to be desired.

`QList` is very expensive to insert in the middle since you have to reallocate everything sitting below the index you are trying to insert at granted you are only shifting pointers around but still.

Normally for data storage I would use an `std::vector< data_struct * >` rather then using vectors of strings.  `QVariant` is quite capable of presenting integers and other types so you don't have to do the conversion up front.

The best suggestion that I can come up with would be to run `gprof` or a similar tool to time where exactly you are spending time and then address that particular piece.

Comment: i've changed it to use a vector of structs and its still slows the app down after maybe 10,000 rows.

Comment: Have you `gprof`ed the app?  Are you doing a full `reset()` or doing the update on every insert?

Comment: @MBU Is your data management separated from the model?  I also looked at the code you posted.  It still shows the use of `QList< QVector< QString > * >` instead of `std::vector< data_struct >` where other then `file_name` and `method` everything else should be numeric.  Strings are more expensive to check then integers or even doubles

Comment: Sorry. I updated my code to what i currently have. on the qt forumn.